# Form Data not getting stored in WordPress database

Tags: database, forms

I have created two pages – **Contribute Page** & **Checkout Page**.

On **Contribute Page** I have following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitnow'])) {
        global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 
    'wp9c_treetweet', 
    array( 
        'name' => $_POST['aname'], 
        'amt' => $_POST['aamt'],
        'dept' => $_POST['adept']
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d',
                '%s' 
    )

);        
}    
?>

<form action="" method="POST" id="addcourse">
<label>Name:<input type="text" name="aname" size="30" required></label>
<label>Amount:<input type="text" name="aamt" size="30" required></label>
<label>Department:<input type="text" name="adept" size="30" required></label>

<input type="submit" name="submitnow" id="addcoursesubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This code is working fine and is inserting the form data properly in database.

To redirect this page to **Checkout Page** I have added following code in **functions.php**:

```
function redirect_from_checkout() {

   if( !isset( $_POST['submitnow'] ) )

       return;

         wp_redirect( home_url( '/checkout/' ) );

         exit;  
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_from_checkout' );
```

After adding redirect code in **functions.php** the redirection is working properly but the form data is not inserting into database table.

Plz help me out with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) about the `template_redirect` hook:

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which
>   template page to load.

So, you are redirecting the user to another page before the template is even loaded, which your form won't load at all. You can use another hook which runs after `template_redirect`, such as `wp_footer`.

You can also redirect the user right after inserting the form in the database, by changing your code to:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitnow'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            'wp9c_treetweet', 
            array( 
                'name' => $_POST['aname'], 
                'amt' => $_POST['aamt'],
                'dept' => $_POST['adept']
            ), 
            array( 
                '%s', 
                '%d',
                        '%s' 
            )

        );
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url( '/checkout/' ));
        exit();
    }
?>
```

This way, if the form is inserted, the user will be redirected afterward.

Comment: Nope its not working.

Comment: Why not simply redirect the user after you insert the form into the database? You can add `wp_safe_redirect()` right after `$wpdb->insert (...)`.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable answers but can u plz modify my code. It will be a great help for me.

Comment: @Minu I updated my answer for you.

Comment: actually the more correct answer is not to submit to the same url as the page being displayed, as this also make sure you can refresh the page after form submission without annoying messages from the browser

Comment: @JackJohansson No the code is not working.